# Prove that the vector z is part of the Linear transformation T(v) = v + z

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Stuck on  this problem. Let z be a (fixed but unknown) vector in $\mathbb R^3$. If the map $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ is given by the formula

$T(v) = v + z$ ($z$ and $v$ are vectors), and is a linear transformation, what would $z$ be?

Both $T(u+v) = T(u)+T(v)$  and $c(T[v]) = T[cv]$  hold because its given that it is a linear transformation.

However when we plug the base case $v = 0$  we get $T(0) = 0 + z$, which we know that z is a fixed unknown vector in $\mathbb R^3$, therefore for this to hold $z$ should equal the $0$ vector.

Comment: Instead of `\mathbb{R}^3` you should have written `$\mathbb{R}^3$`. For more, see this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that and fixed it asap

Comment: So, what’s your question?

Comment: What would the vector z be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got it. Since T is linear $T(0) = 0 = 0 + z$ So we get $z = 0$

Answer (score 1):

The only z vector that would make this a linear transformation would be z=0.

For a linear transformation, T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)

Using your definition for T, T(w) = w + z , then

T(u+v) = (u+v) + z

T(u) = u + z

T(v) = v + z

so u + v + z = u + v + 2z

z = 2z  ==> z = 0.